# Populate a single embedded document

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a `user` model that contains a single embedded document `address` that is defined like this:

```
let userSchema = new Schema({
  id: ObjectId,
  //...
  address: {
    type: AddressSchema,
    required: true,
    default: () => ({})
  },
  //...
});
const UserModel = mongoose.model('User', userSchema);
```

The `Address` contains a reference for a `Country` model:

```
let AddressSchema = new Schema({
  country: {
    type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'Country'
  }
});
const AddressModel = mongoose.model('Address', AddressSchema);
```

Where the `Country` definition is:

```
let countrySchema = new Schema({
  id: ObjectId,
  name: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    unique: true
  }
});
const CountryModel = mongoose.model('Country', countrySchema);
```

And this is how I am populating the user documents:

```
  let user = await UserModel
    .findByIdAndUpdate(
      someId,
      operators,
      { new: true }
    )
    .populate({
      path: 'address.country',
      model: CountryModel
    })
```

When I am running a `console.log(JSON.stringify(user.address))`, the object is not well fetched, as you may see in the comment of the code below, there is an additional `_id` field that I don't know how to get rid of :

```
  {
   "country":{
      "_id":{// ============> How to get rid of this _id field?
         "_id":"5b56ecab8cba833c28e0e613",
         "name":"USA",
         "__v":0
      }
   }
```

There is something wrong either with my way of using the `populate` method or how I embed the `Address` schema in the `User`, but I am not able to figure it out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that the `Address` was saved in the `user` document in a way that does not help the `populate` method to retrieve the `country`

The JSON with which I was saving the address in the user was like that:

```
{
  // Other fields of the user
  address: {
    country : {
      _id: "5b56ecab8cba833c28e0e613"
    }
  }
}
```

But changing it to this form solved the problem:

```
 {
    // Other fields of the user
    address: {
      country : "5b56ecab8cba833c28e0e613"
    }
 }
```